# Buttons don't work inside of a List group

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I've added a button inside of a list group which is inside of a popover and it just won't work. I've tried a bunch of things such as getting rid of btn class, changing ul to div and rewriting all the code inside, in the js file rewrote the click function a lot of times, changed .click() function to .on('click', ...) function, even deleted the button itself and made the list group item the button (list-group-item-action), nothing worked.
How do I make this button work?

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rarenex/sqfuk49z/

```
<!--HTML-->
<ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
  <li class="list-group-item cart-order">
    Latte
    <!-- THE BUTTON -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger delete-order">x</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

```
// Javascript
$(function() {
  // Clicking the cart popover
  $('.btn-cart').popover({
    html: true,
    'content': () => {
      return $('#cart-content').html();
    }
  });

  // Clicking the trash can button
  $('.delete-order').click(function() {
    alert("YAY");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The popover gets removed from page and re-inserted as needed. This will cause any event listeners you add to it's content on page load to be lost

Use [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) on the button

```
$(document).on('click','.delete-order',function() {
   alert("YAY");
});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/sqfuk49z/36/)**</kbd>

Comment: Thanks a lot, couldn't figure this out on my own for a looong time

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
  $(document).on('click','.delete-order',function(event){
    alert("YAY");
  });
```